# Why does reading /dev/random byte by byte block so often?

Tags: linux, shell, random

The following call returns fast:

```
time dd if=/dev/random bs=1024 count=1
.... 0+1 records in
0+1 records out
49 bytes (49 B) copied, 0.000134028 s, 366 kB/s

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys    0m0.002s
```

However, if `/dev/random` is read one byte after another:

```
for i in {1..500}; do dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1 status=none; done
```

The loop reads several bytes, then block for several seconds, and then read another several bytes. Typing random characters on keyboard speeds up the process a lot, like if there was not enough entropy in the random pool. After all the loop takes many minutes to complete.

What makes reading `/dev/random` byte by byte a lot slower than reading a block from it?

Uname -a:

```
Linux ... 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in your question:

```
49 bytes (49 B) copied, 0.000134028 s, 366 kB/s
```

So it didn't copy 1024 bytes like told it but only a few and then stops. I quess this is the same amount that you would have gotten in the loop before it blocks.

/dev/random is slow because it needs to collect the randomness from different sources and as long as none is available it doesn't output anything.

Use /dev/urandom if you need faster numbers.

Comment: Thank you sharp eyes! Could you please elaborate on why `dd` prematurely terminates before the entire block size is filled?

Comment: @Howard Your answer lies [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes).

Comment: Or to make it short: bs=1024 (in this case) does only tell dd to use buckets of the size 1024 *if it gets so much*. Try reversing the parameters: bs=1 count=1024 and it will block.

Comment: Or by example: 
echo "foo" > y; 
dd if=y of=z bs=1024  ---->
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
4 bytes (4 B) copied, 0,00050546 s, 9,9 kB/s

Answer (score 1):

Unless you very definitely need `/dev/random`, you should use `/dev/urandom`.

As you have noticed `/dev/random` blocks when there is not enough entropy in the pool to service the request, but `urandom` will fall back to a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) if there is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am aware of /dev/urandom being the non-blocking pool, however in the question, /dev/random did not appear to be short of just 500 bytes of entropy.

Comment: While it's true that you normally should use /dev/urandom, this doesn't answer the question